# Add firstchild to newly added element

Tags: javascript

I need to create a new child to an existing element. The question [add onclick event to newly added element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3316207/505893) helped me a lot.

I just can not define it as the first child. I can place it using `position`, but this is still insufficient. I searched on sites about JavaScript, but I found nothing.

Here is my code:

```
if( !document.getElementById('callbackButton')){
  callback = function(){
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.id= 'callbackButton';
  var textbutton =document.createTextNode("Liste des années d'étude");
  button.appendChild(textbutton );
  button.style.position='absolute';
  button.style.top="60px";
  button.style.left="45px";
  button.style.width="200px";
  button.style.height="18px";
  button.onclick = function(){
    getElementsByIdStarWith('etageres-virtuelle')[0].innerHTML = oldInnerHtml;
    document.getElementById('etageres-virtuelles-etudes-germaniques').innerHTML =      oldInnerHtml;   
    wrapPager();
  };
  document.getElementById('etageres-virtuelles-etudes-germaniques').appendChild(button);
 };
```

This code works very well.

But this code doesn't work:

```
document.getElementById('etageres-virtuelles-etudes-germaniques').firstChild.nodeValue = button;
document.getElementById('etageres-virtuelles-etudes-germaniques').firstChild.nodeData = button;
```

This is not what I want. I want to display this new element on first place.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (untested):

```
var yourEl = document.getElementById('etageres-virtuelles-etudes-germaniques');
yourEl.insertBefore(button, yourEl.firstChild);
```

Comment: I tested this code and it works very well

thank you very much for the help and quick
perfect thanks :)  @let'sgo