# Add and remove div from body in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm kinda new to javascript, and probably there are other people who already asked similar question, but I hope you can help me anyway.
I'm trying a simple basic operation of add/remove of a div.
The add works fine, the remove is never called.

```
function $(el) {
    return document.getElementById(el);
}

function remove() {
    console.log("remove called");
    var child = $('second');
}

function addContainer() {
    console.log("addContainer called");
    var aContainer = document.createElement('div');
    aContainer.setAttribute('id', 'second');
    aContainer.innerHTML = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"remove()\">second</a>";
    document.body.appendChild(aContainer);
}
```

In the addContainer I try to add the onclick function callback, but apparently it doesn't work.

Here the jsfiddle of reference
http://jsfiddle.net/m8kyav2b/

DO you know why 
1- the remove function is never called? 
2- once I click on the remove link, the innerHTML is removed, but not the div "second"?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: `$('second')` is a jQuery selector.  No jQuery is present.

Comment: @Xero - It is not a jQuery selector.

Comment: I defined the function $(el) at the beginning of the script. I used the same function in other scripts, never had problems with it. Is there any problem with the definition?
Edit: @Xero: don't worry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this, it will work:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m8kyav2b/5/)

```
function $(el) {
    return document.getElementById(el);
}

function removeit() {
    alert("remove called");
    var child = $('second');
    child.remove();


}

function addContainer() {
    console.log("addContainer called");
    var aContainer = document.createElement('div');
    aContainer.setAttribute('id', 'second');
    aContainer.innerHTML = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"removeit()\">second</a>";
    document.body.appendChild(aContainer);
}
```

SIDENOTE:

Calling remove() as your function won't work as it is a native javascript function.
You didn't actually remove the div in your function, too!

Comment: Hmm, I noticed a little hiccup, if you click "second", it disappears, and you click "move", it appears again, but you cannot hide it again.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, really appreciated.
Not bad posting here for the first time and having the problem solved in 10 mins :)

Comment: I don't see why you cannot use `remove` as a function name. It is not a [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords). Saying it cannot be used is completely invalid.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 thanks, I thought wrong there then. But how can you use remove as a self-made function name then?

Comment: @baao - You can call it via `window.remove()` if your function lives in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a helpful link: [Remove element by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id). The below code is tested and works (it will upon mouse over delete the HTML tag, so basically just change the syntax around a little to have it delete what ever tag you want.

```
<p id="el" onmouseover="remove()">test</p> <!--we are deleting with JavaScript this HTML <p> tag. -->

function remove() {
  var element = document.getElementById("el"); /* finding and assigning element to variable element */
  document  
  element.parentNode.removeChild(el); // then deleting the parent and child (please refer to link)
}
```

as far as the rest of your question. Look here: [add onclick event to newly added element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316207/add-onclick-event-to-newly-added-element-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

`remove` is never called because `remove` in your `<a>` tag is referring to the native function `remove` (to be specific, [`HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.remove`/`ChildNode.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove)) instead of yours. This is why only the text is removed, since `ChildNode.remove` targets its child.

To reference your function, do

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.remove();"></a>
```

Or even better:

```
var aContainer = document.createElement('div'),
    anchor = document.createElement("a");
aContainer.setAttribute('id', 'second');
a.innerText = "second";
a.addEventListener("click", remove);
aContainer.appendChild(a);
document.body.appendChild(aContainer);
```