# How to get an onclick property in Rails form tags?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do something so simple, and yet I can't get it to work.

```
radio_button_tag(:hw_choice, "Completed", onclick: {alert("I work!"); } )
```

I need to use `radio_button_tag`, and what I want to do is to do some js any time the radio button changes. I've tried many varieties of the above, option: { `on_click`:, none of them even generate the `onclick` html attribute, so this should be pretty simple, html/rails helper problem.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`radio_button_tag` has four parameters, the third parameter is the `checked` and the fourth parameter is the HTML options you desire.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag

Add a `true` or `false` as the third parameter. Enclose the JavaScript in quotes. Also, you don't need the parentheses around the parameters.

```
radio_button_tag :hw_choice, "Completed", false, onclick: "window.alert('I work!');"
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316207/add-onclick-event-to-newly-added-element-in-javascript/3316226#3316226), one option is to add an event listener to the button using javascript.

```
button = document.getElementById("id")
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    //do stuff here
}, false);
```

(This solution would be implemented on the frontend rather than the backend, which may not be ideal)

Comment: Good answer too, but I was looking for the detail that the first answerer gave me. Thanks!

Comment: @pitosalas glad I could help!