# HTML in JS - Quotes rendered incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html

```
getFeederInfoWindow: function (i) {
    var windowContent = "<button onclick='feeders.getFeederLoadingData(" + i + ",'summer')\">Summer</button>"
}
```

The method signature is basically: `feeders.getFeederLoadingData: function (i, selectedSeason)`

When the HTML page is loaded, Chrome inspection shows the `<button>` is rendered as follow:

**Rendered:**
`<button onclick="feeders.getFeederLoadingData(203," summer')">Summer</button>`

But this is what I wanted:

**Desired** `<button onclick="feeders.getFeederLoadingData(203,'summer')">Summer</button>`

Bit of an embarrassing question, but I cannot figure out how I have messed up the quotes.

Thank you.

Comment: *"I cannot figure out how I have messed up the quote"* You are using `"` to *end* the `onclick` value but are using `'` to *start* it. That won't work, you have to end with the same quotation mark as you start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote after "onclick" is just a single quote. That should do the job:

```
getFeederInfoWindow: function (i) {
    var windowContent = "<button onclick=\"feeders.getFeederLoadingData(" + i + ",'summer')\">Summer</button>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You attempt to start your attribute value with `'` and then end it with `"`.

Nest your quotes correctly.

Better yet: Don't generate HTML by smashing strings together. Use `createElement`, `addEventListener` and friends.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the starting quotation for the `onclick` attribute:

```
"<button onclick='\"feeders.getFeederLoadingData(" + i + ",'summer')\">Summer</button>"
//                ^
//          THIS WAS MISSING
```

In general, it is a good idea to separate the DOM elements' behavior from their markup. This can be done:

- [Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements):

  ```
  $("<button>Summer</button>").on('click', function () { ... });
  ```
- [Without using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3316207/1492578):

  ```
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = "Summer";
  button.onclick = function () { ... };
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You try to use single quotes for the inline javascript like below

```
var windowContent = "<button onclick='feeders.getFeederLoadingData(i,'summer')' >Summer </button>";
```