# Javascript list with clickable elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, list

I am working on a script that would generate random list of 100 elements where every third element would be clickable. So far I am stuck at stage below. Any ideas how to progress?

```
var hundred = Array(100);
hundred.toString();

for (i = 0; i < hundred.length; i++) {
  document.write("Item " + (i + 1) + " of" + hundred.length + "</br>")
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `document.write`, use `document.createElement` to create an element and assign them event listener and append these elements to an element in html or `document.body`

Comment: So you need to write out a button or link or something.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: full example

```
var hundred = Array(100);
var node;
hundred.toString();

for (i = 0; i < hundred.length; i++) {
  if(i%3===0 && i!==0){
  node = document.createElement("button");
  node.addEventListener('click', function() { alert('clicked'); });
  node.innerHTML = 'clickablke';
  } else {
  node = document.createElement("div");
  node.innerHTML = 'just div';
  }

  document.body.appendChild(node);
}
```

Comment: *every third element would be clickable*?

Comment: And how is it clickable? ;)

Comment: Every third element would go bold after clicking.

Answer (score 0):

I used buttons. every third element will be clickable. remaining elements will have disabled property

```js
var hundred = Array(100);
hundred.toString();
for (i = 0; i < hundred.length; i++) {
 
  if(i%3===0 && i!==0){
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML ="Click "+i ;
  
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(button);
    
  }else{
      var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML ="Click "+i ;
   button.disabled = true;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(button);
    
    
    
  }
}
```

Comment: @rajesh jquery removed

Answer (score 0):

As commented,

> Instead of using document.write, use document.createElement to create an element and assign them event listener and append these elements to an element in html or `document.body`

```js
var hundred = Array(100);
for (i = 0; i < hundred.length; i++) {
  let el = document.createElement('span');
  el.textContent = i + " ";
  if((i+1) % 3 === 0){
    el.classList.add('clickable')
    el.addEventListener("click", notify)
  }
  document.body.appendChild(el)
}

function notify(){
  this.classList.add('clicked')
  console.log(this.textContent)
}
```

```css
.clickable{
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.clicked{
  color: gray;
}
```

#### References

- [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)
- [Document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [add onclick event to newly added element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316207/add-onclick-event-to-newly-added-element-in-javascript)

Comment: and how would I go with changing look of every third element after clicking. So when the script loads all elements look all the same. After clicking every third it goes bold underlined etc.?

Comment: Thanks! I see it now.

Comment: @Kobiasz24 Please check the update

Answer (score 0):

First you need create the element. Then apply the `onclick` with this consition `i%3 == 0` to every `3` rd element

**Updated**

after click its a bolder using `classList.add()`

```js
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  var s = document.createElement('SPAN');
  if (i % 3 == 0) {
    s.className = 'clickable';
    s.onclick = clicks;
  }
  s.textContent=i;
  document.body.appendChild(s)
}

function clicks() {
  console.log(this.innerHTML)
  this.classList.add('bold')
}
```

```css
.clickable {
  color: red;
}
.bold{
font-weight:bolder;
}
```

Comment: Just a pointer, if you are using `.innerHTML=`, do not update it in loop. Create a big HTML string and perform bulk operation.

Comment: @Rajesh I was just use with showing the element with that.

Comment: and how would I go with changing look of every third element after clicking. So when the script loads all elements look all the same. After clicking every third it goes bold underlined etc.?

Comment: see the Updated answer @Kobiasz24\

Answer (score 0):

Multiple wayst to do this, i'd make an event listener to every item reference, hence: every third clickable element goes bold:

```js
 var hundred = Array(100);
hundred.toString();
var btn = Array(100);
for (i = 0; i < hundred.length+1; i++) {
  btn = document.createElement("p");
  btn.innerHTML="Item " + (i-1 + 1) + " of" +   hundred.length + "</br>";

  if(i%3===0 && i!==0){
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() { 
this.style.fontWeight = 'bold'; }, false);


  }
    document.body.appendChild(btn);                    
}
```