# How to call onclick in inline defined HTML

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I have the following code to display a dialog with three buttons. I'm trying to execute a specific function depending on the button clicked. However so far I have had no luck in getting the functions to execute:

```
  this.myMarkers.push({
    latitude: val["Latitude"],
    longitude: val["Longitude"],
    title: 'Tree ' + val["TreeID"],
    custom: {id: 123456},
    infoWindow: {content: `
            <div id="content">
              <div id="siteNotice"></div>
              <h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Tree ${val["TreeID"]}</h1>
              <div id="bodyContent">
                <p>Description: ${val["Description"]}</p>
                <p>Fruit Bearing: ${val["FruitBearing"]}</p>
                <button type="button" onclick="this.updateTree()">Update</button>
                <button type="button" onclick=${this.editTreeInfo()}>Edit Info</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="${this.showTreeHistory()}">Historical</button>
              </div>
            </div>`}
  });

  updateTree(){
    console.log("Update Tree: ");
  }

  editTreeInfo(){
    console.log("Edit Tree: ");
  }

  showTreeHistory(){
    console.log("Show Tree History: ");
  }
```

In the console, after the page loads, the following is outputted:

```
welcome.js:56 Edit Tree: 
welcome.js:60 Show Tree History: 
welcome.js:56 Edit Tree: 
welcome.js:60 Show Tree History: 
welcome.js:56 Edit Tree: 
welcome.js:60 Show Tree History: 
welcome.js:56 Edit Tree: 
...
```

And when clicking the buttons, nothing happens - except for:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.updateTree is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)
```

Nothing happens for the other buttons. I have tried using `click.delegate` but this doesn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: did you try this ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316207/add-onclick-event-to-newly-added-element-in-javascript 
Idea is to attach event listeners after the html is created.

Comment: hmm looks promising - tried this `<button type="button" onclick=function() { updateTree(); };>Update</button>` but get an error: `
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( `

Comment: Im not sure on Aurelia. But in Javascript above is how I would go about attaching events to dynamically created html. Or perhaps use jquery and bind classes or ids to events. Having said that, here is a link which might help but I'm not sure - http://www.jeremyg.net/entry/adding-a-view-to-a-custom-attribute-in-aurelia

Comment: I should mention this element is a point displayed on a google map - this might affect something - not sure..

Comment: Also, since you say, your html is rendered nicely you could get the element and attach an event separately. something like this 

`var element = document.getElementById('id'); 
element.onclick = function(){// handle click };`

needless to say, this must be executed everytime you render your html as id would be uniq.

Comment: BTW, doesn't it look like a typo ? `<button type="button" onclick="this.updateTree()">Update</button>`
shouldn't this be `<button type="button" onclick=${this.updateTree()}>Update</button>` as your other buttons follow this syntax.

Comment: `<button type="button" onclick=${this.updateTree()}>Update</button>` Gave this a try - seems to fire as soon as the page loads...

Answer (score 2):

I really don't think this is the way to go about it, but a quick fix might be to write your onclick function like so:

```
onclick='(${this.updateTree})()'
```

Your current code is executing at once because of the parantheses immediately after `updateTree`

Be wary though that with this method you will not reference your function but rather copy it to each pushed marker. The onclick in html will look something like this:

```
onclick="(function () {
        // ALL CODE from inside updateTree function
    })()"
```

Which mean that you wont be able to use any code from the viewmodel which resides outside that function. Lets say you have a variable in the viewmodel like `this.variable = "not undefined"`. That will be undefined when the onclick action triggers.

---

I'd probably try to import the TemplatingEngine from aurelia-framework, create the infowindow in a variable first, and then enhance it with the templatingengine. Then you should be able to use `click.delegate`:

```
import { TemplatingEngine, inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(TemplatingEngine)
export class App {
  templatingEngine: TemplatingEngine;

  constructor(te: TemplatingEngine) {
    this.templatingEngine = te;
  }

prepareMarker(){
 let infoWindowContent = document.createElement('div');
 infoWindowContent.id = "content";
 infoWindowContent.innerHTML = `<div id="siteNotice"></div>
          <h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Tree ${val["TreeID"]}</h1>
          <div id="bodyContent">
            <p>Description: ${val["Description"]}</p>
            <p>Fruit Bearing: ${val["FruitBearing"]}</p>
            <button type="button" click.delegate="updateTree()">Update</button>
            <button type="button" click.delegate="editTreeInfo()">Edit Info</button>
            <button type="button" click.delegate="showTreeHistory()">Historical</button>
          </div>`;
   this.templatingEngine.enhance({ element: infoWindowContent, bindingContext: this });

   this.myMarkers.push({
    ...
    infoWindow: infoWindowContent
   });
  }
```

I'm assuming you're using google maps, and from what I know, they accept a htmlelement as well as a string as 'content': [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions)

Sidenote: If you push more than 1 marker, you're going to have multiple elements of the same id(content, sideNotice, firstHeading, bodyContent). You should probably swap all ids for classes.

Answer (score 0):

`this.updateTree` is not a function because your function `updateTree` is defined in the context of a `window` object, while `this` refers to the DOM element.  Try removing `this` in the button `onclick` call,

`onclick=updateTree()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Gave it a go, but no joy:

`<button type="button" onclick="updateTree()">Update</button>`

outputs

`(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: updateTree is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`

Comment: Hmm, your syntax is interesting.   Don't you need to define `updateTree` as `function updateTree() {...}` rather than just `updateTree() {...}`

Comment: Nope, it's the Aurelia framework which uses ES6. The JS looks like [this](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/skeleton-esnext/src/welcome.js)

Comment: Where, in the HTML or the JS? You can't declare functions like that in Aurelia.

Comment: This declaration needs to be made in JS