# todo list with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I made the Todo list in JavaScript. I just use JavaScript.  I want the work to be completed when the `<li>`  element is pressed on. I created a method for this. how do I do this process?

```
.completed {
      text-decoration: line-through;
    }
```

I want the post drawn when it is complete. I have prepared a CSS for it

```
let todos = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Javascript",
    completed: true
  },
];

function render() { /* I list object */
  flen = todos.length;
  text = "<ul id=myUL>";
  for (i = 0; i < flen; i++) {
    text +=
      '<li  id="' +
      todos[i].id +
      '">' +
      todos[i].title +

      "</li>";
  }
  text += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
render();


function completedTodo(e) { /*it's method */

}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this function ? How do you define *completed* ? What have you tried for this function ?

Comment: We don't know what "completing the work" means in the context of your app. Does the item simply disappear? Change color with a strikethrough? Move to a "completed section"? Please update your post with the relevant information to get better help.

Comment: @Weedoze, @Austin Who cares what the function does? How is that relevant info? OP needs to attach a click listener to the `li` elements which will call the function. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316207/add-onclick-event-to-newly-added-element-in-javascript

Comment: you need a delegated event listener,

Comment: @Shomz I think that the question is simply not clear enough. OP is saying `how do I do this process?` - I understand it as *process* means the algorithm to complete a task.

Answer (score 1):

Attach an event listener to the `li` and then when clicked you add the class of `completed` to it.

```
document.querySelectorAll('li')
 .forEach((item) => {
   item.addEventListener('click', () => {
     item.className += " completed";
   })
})
```

Comment: Also, remember to remove the `eventListener` when you finish doing what you want.