# Why isn't my function related to an onclick workin?

Tags: javascript

I'm studding HTML, CSS and JS and while I was creating an exercise, I was forced to stop due to an error. I created an button dynamically, setted an onclick to it and then created a function with that onclick. The problem is that the function isn't working, at leats it doesn't made anything till now.

```
let formularys = document.querySelector('section#formulary')
let slct = document.createElement('select')
let opts = document.createElement('option')
let optp = document.createElement('option')
let fbtn = document.querySelector('input#formularybtn')
let nbtn = document.createElement('input')
let br = document.createElement('br')

slct.id = 'pors'
slct.size = '2'
opts.value = 'rsite'
opts.innerHTML = 'Rate site'
optp.value = 'rp'
optp.innerHTML = 'Rate products'
nbtn.setAttribute('type', 'button')
nbtn.setAttribute('value', 'Next')
nbtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'nbutton')

function nbutton(){
    console.log('Next working')
    /*if(slct.selectedIndex == 1){
        console.log('Valid rate choose')
    }*/`enter code here`
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add onclick event to newly added element in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316207/add-onclick-event-to-newly-added-element-in-javascript)

Comment: You created all these elements but never appended them to any part of your page. So, they are clearly not yet part of your page.

Comment: You must append the button to the DOM and change in  'onclick', 'nbutton()' the statement setAttribute

Comment: Duplicate of [Radio button onclick not working](/q/32139849/4642212): exactly the same cause: `nbutton` doesn’t do anything. Since the `onclick` attibute eval’s the string inside, the reference to the function is discarded. Calling it requires parentheses. But `onclick` is bad practice anyway.

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using setAttribute you can just do

```
nbtn.onclick = nbutton
```

in javascript, onclick isn't a string but a function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are not appending your html code generated from JavaScript to DOM. You can either append to main DOM like below

```
document.body.appendChild(nbtn);
document.body.appendChild(optp);
```

or you can append them to some parent div by first getting div id

```
document.getElementById("divId").appendChild(nbtn);
```

where divId is id of your div where you want to add this html.

Also you should assign event listener in correct way as suggested by Tony and Rashed Rahat.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
element.onclick = function() { alert('onclick requested'); };
```

Comment: That’s not an adequate replacement for `nbtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'nbutton')`.