# How to add onClick attribute to a button with JS?

Tags: javascript, onclick

How can I add onClick attribute to this button using JS?

`<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="41" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">BUY NOW</button>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add onclick event to newly added element in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316207/add-onclick-event-to-newly-added-element-in-javascript)

Comment: You should try like this - <button type="button" onClick="yourFunction()" name="add-to-cart" value="41" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">BUY NOW</button>

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Jquery:

```
"your element".addEventListener('click', function(){ 
     alert('hey');
 }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the JS function **.addEventListener()**, [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) you'll find a well done explenation of It.

What I sugger you to do is to add an **Id** to your button tag and then use the **document.getElementById()** *(if you don't know what this JS function does read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById?retiredLocale=it))* to find your button and apply to It the .addEventListner() function to add a click behaviour.

I made a simple code example below, take a look at It and let me know if this answer is what you're searching for.

```js
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('myButton').classList.toggle('toggled');
});
```

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}

button.toggled {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <button type=submit id="myButton">
      CLICK ME
    </button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in js, you will have to either use [.addEventListener()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) function or [.onClick()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) function that are triggered whenever the button is clicked

you can also use the .onClick inside of your html

```
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="41" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" onClick="function_name">BUY NOW</button>
```

sidenote: if you want to access the button element inside your javascript you can add an Id to your button tag and then use the [document.getElementById()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)  or use let var = [document.getElementByClass()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) but be aware to use var[0] to access the button element in case you filtered it by class